# Simple donut chart in Microcharts for c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, skiasharp

I want to use [Microcharts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/microcharts-elegant-cross-platform-charts-for-any-app/) to create simple graphs in my `XAML` code for a C# Windows **.Net 4.7 project** in Visual Studio.

I'm using the following code to create a window with **WPF**, some grid rows and columns and display it. Ideally one of those rows/columns will display the chart I am interested in. I'm not sure if `Microcharts` can be used in my project since it isn't a `UWP` project, and I can't change it all for the sake of this one graph.

```
<Window x:Class="Myproject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:chartingToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
        xmlns:microcharts="clr-namespace:Microcharts.Forms;assembly=Microcharts.Forms"
        Title="Analysis Display" FontFamily="Candara" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="24"
        Width="Auto" Height="Auto" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <microcharts:ChartView x:Name="chartView" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The warning on `<microcharts:ChartView x:Name="chartView" />` as per the example in the link:

> The name "ChartView" does not exist in the namespace
>   "clr-namespace:Microcharts.Forms;assembly=Microcharts.Forms".

Can anyone help me figure out how to set up the basic XAML of this implementation? I installed Microcharts from the **NuGet** packages so I assume somehow that I can run it here without creating a new UWP project.

Thank you

Comment: WPF is not UWP...

Comment: Have you added the appropriate assembly reference to your project?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Microcharts supports WPF.